# Why ASP.NET Role provider is build upond username checking, and not the ID

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership

So far I've seen several custom implementations of ASP.NET Role Providers, and all of them comply to a base class requirenment that the Role-checking is done based on string username. (For example `IsUserInRole(string username)`). Is this requirenment for Role Provider based on the fact that this string username will be a uniqe key for user entity?

My user class uses GUID Id as a uniqe identifier of the user instance.

P.S. I do understand that I need to use thie GUID Id when setting authentication cookies. Just want to make sure that I understand the motivation behind user name role associations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely because it's very easy to get the username from the IPrincipal.  So you can easily do `IsUserInRole(User.Identity.Name)`

More importantly, the FormsAuthentication system has to be able to rely on the IPrincipal to do validation at the Authorization level, and the only information that available is the username.

Comment: @MaximV.Pavlov - How would you otherwise log in?  You have to look them up by username.  Because the only information you have is username and password.  If username was not unique, then how would you know which user was trying to log in?

Comment: @MystereMan I thought everyone's users groups were supposed to memorize a GUID?

Comment: Well, In the world of Facebook/Twitter-retrieved login credentials one hardly needs a unique user name. I think it should have been renamed to unique identifier (UID) and that would be more correct. Thanks for the info though.